# Find a span with specific text in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I need to implement the following logic:

If a `span` that is after an `a` (which has an href that is `/100-percent-remote-jobs` -- this is relevant) has `"Anywhere (100% Remote) Only"` as its `innerText`, do this code:

```js
  const jobs = [];

  for (let enlace of jobPost) {
    await page.goto(enlace);
    const eachJob = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const tmp = {};
      tmp.job = document.querySelector('.listing-header-container h1').innerText;
      tmp.company = document.querySelector('.company-card h2 a').innerText;

      return tmp;
    });

    jobs.push(eachJob);
  }

  console.log(jobs);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's somewhat difficult to follow what you need here. Are you scraping https://weworkremotely.com/100-percent-remote-jobs? I assume you want to extract some info from these listings, but all of them seem to match the text you want, so I'm not sure why you'd need to validate that. Can you edit the post to show the site you're scraping, or a snippet of relevant markup, along with the expected output you want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
page.$$eval('a[href*="100-percent-remote-jobs"] span', spans => spans.find(span => span.innerText === 'Anywhere (100% Remote) Only'))
```